# Unable to deploy ASP.NET Core app to IIS - Bad Gateway

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

Have been struggling to get this to work, I have a standard .NET Core API that I want to host on a remote IIS server, the issue is most of the tutorials are for ASP.NET 5/vNext and don't explain what happens once you run your `dotnet publish`. 
My bindings are correct but I'm not sure if i'm pointing at the right folder.

In my output folder I have **publish** and **wwwroot** as well as `config.json` and some other json files. When I point IIS to the **wwwroot** folder I get:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

I get 404s if I try point it to any other folder. I have HttpPlatformHandler 1.2 installed. My `project.json` is as follows:

```
  {
  "compilationOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot"
    ]
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict.EF": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002700"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "imports": "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  },

  "content": [
    "wwwroot",
    "config.json",
    "web.config"
  ],

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],

  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

I took elements of [this sample](https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples/blob/master/HelloMvcApi/project.json) for my `project.json`.

Comment: see this link https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2135

Answer (score 7):

I pointed IIS to the root folder to the application folder and NOT the wwwroot and it worked.

The IIS server needs to have [DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-WindowsHosting.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/6/1/46116DFF-29F9-4FF8-94BF-F9BE05BE263B/DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-WindowsHosting.exe)

Comment: And for ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM the link is: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817246

Comment: @StefanIancu thank you so much, you saved my life :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Physical path in IIS should point to the wwwroot folder from your publish output.

[image]

The approot folder also needs to be placed in the same dir as the wwwroot folder.

I've found it helpful to try running web.cmd in the approot folder and seeing if it'll start.  It's easier to see the startup exceptions (if there are any) when running web.cmd.  You can also change the stdoutLogEnabled flag in the wwwroot/web.config file to true to get any startup exceptions from IIS.

Finally, on at least one occasion, after hitting my head against a wall for an hour trying to get it working, I rebooted my IIS server and suddenly it was working correctly.  Obviously a last resort if it's a prod server

Comment: thankfully it's our staging server! My issue is when I publish, there is no approot folder, it's really a confusing structure, I'll try post a picture if that helps

Comment: you definitely need an approot folder.  that's where all the code lives.  I publish my application from Visual Studio and it outputs both the wwwroot folder and the approot folder so the issue is probably with how you're publishing.   Please post the photo of your output directory.

Comment: @TrevorWard, approot folder in RC2 project? Your answer may be for RC1?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue on Windows 2012 R2 server when I deploy site on IIS; bad gateway issue. Yes, I was using .Net Core 2.0. On IIS I had application pool "No Managed Code"; Managed pipeline "Integrated" and still had the same issue. 
Solution was install [DotNetCore.2.0.0-WindowsHosting.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/1/D/B1D7D5BF-3920-47AA-94BD-7A6E48822F18/DotNetCore.2.0.0-WindowsHosting.exe) on server and success :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
when publishing to set Seld-Contained for Deployment Mode.
[image]