# How to deploy or run NETCore.App 1.0.0-rc2-3002702

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

After I migrated my app to RC2 or to be very specific V. 1.0.0-rc2-3002702 I'm struggling with deployment of my app. I have noticed that folder "approot" in publish directory does not exist anymore and also with it "web.cmd" file. I have tried to deploy it on IIS but all I got is page not found "**This site can’t be reached**". On the official MS dotnet core documentation web site it is just like "Create new website in your IIS edit basic settings and you are good to go..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe my answer to a similar post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37301527/166928

Don't point IIS to wwwroot like in RC1 but to the root folder.

Also, your server needs to have [DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-WindowsHosting.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/6/1/46116DFF-29F9-4FF8-94BF-F9BE05BE263B/DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-WindowsHosting.exe)

Comment: Thanks It is partially an answer. I have made it by creating application under default web site and pointing it to app-pool that uses No Managed Code and yes to root folder of published application.
Also there was a loot of problems with magnifying of AngularJS files with bower and so on... And finally I'we got it working... Also one tip: in ConnectionStrings it is best to use Trusted_Connection=False; and to provide user name and password.

Comment: Not magnifying of angular :) but minify (Uglify) :)

Comment: For me it works fine with Trusted_connection=true. I just change the user in the app_pool to meet my requirements.

Comment: Great. :) for me not... I was struggling for hours to find that last problem... Why data is not displayed. Than I figured out that it was trusted connection.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ensure that the server you are attempting to deploy to has the [HTTPPlatformHandler](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler) installed.

You also need to ensure that your project.json has the IISIntegration package referenced and has an include containing your web.config. It should look something like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*" 
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Your web.config will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
           resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"  
                forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

*Note:* The environment variables LAUNCHER_PATH and LAUNCHER_ARGS may cause you some headaches if you are not publishing from inside Visual Studio.

To get an RC2 site up and running on an Azure VM, I had to change that line to look like this:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments="./YourAppEntryPoint.dll" 
            stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
            forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
```